# Android Highlight on Touch Down in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I've been googling for hours on this, SO seems to have a bunch of questions, some with accepted answers, but they don't make sense.

I have a ListView and I want that, onTouch, an item be highlighted, but if the user moves their finger and doesn't "complete" the touch (their finger is outside the view when it is lifted) then the highlight should go away.

If I try to consume the touches by having the following in my `View`:

```
onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev) {

   ....logic

   //return false so this view keeps consuming the touches
   return false;

}
```

The the touch never gets propagated to the `ListView` and `onItemClick` never gets called. I can hack my way through this by having my adapter be a listener to all of the views and pass "complete" touch events to the adapter, which will pass it back to the `ListView` which can then pass it on to whoever, but this just seems ludicrous.

For the record, the highlight I'm trying to perform is a moderately complex highlight (involving changing the backgrounds of multiple, dynamic, subviews, so I can't just use a `StateDrawable`...at least I don't think so, do `StateDrawables` work on multiple subviews?

iOS handles this very simply in their `UITableViewDelegate`, it seems crazy that this is so hard on android, I must be missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple selector?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Android development, Gil. Maybe I could, I'd love a link, example, or at least an elaboration on your comment. I'm thinking I can't because the "drawable" would be unable to be defined because of the dynamic nature of the subviews that need to be highlighted, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a selector on the list items.

Define a selector 'item_sel.xml' in res/drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_highlight_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_default_color"/>
</selector>
```

where `my_default_color` and `my_highlight_color` are colors defined by you, for instance in res/values/colors.xml. Then set this selector as the background of your *item* view (not the ListView), that is:

```
 android:background="@drawable/item_sel.xml"
```

You should be good to go from here.

Comment: What I was looking for was the `duplicateParentState` property. That combined with a selector, got it working for me. Like I said, I'm pretty new to android and still trying to figure out what everything means - finding `duplicateParentState` in the docs was a lightbulb moment